# log4j error: Value not resolved by key: project_report_directory

Tags: java, log4j

I try to use log4j for my project and created follow logic:

**Log** class:

```
public class Log {
    //Initialize Log4j instance
    private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName());

    //We can use it when starting tests
    public static void startLog (String testClassName){
        Log.info("Test is Starting...");
    }

    //We can use it when ending tests
    public static void endLog (String testClassName){
        Log.info("Test is Ending...");
    }

    //Info Level Logs
    public static void info (String message) {
        Log.info(message);
    }

    //Warn Level Logs
    public static void warn (String message) {
        Log.warn(message);
    }

    //Error Level Logs
    public static void error (String message) {
        Log.error(message);
    }

    //Fatal Level Logs
    public static void fatal (String message) {
        Log.fatal(message);
    }

    //Debug Level Logs
    public static void debug (String message) {
        Log.debug(message);
    }
}
```

**log4j.properties**:

```
#logging level
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file, console

# stdout settings
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.logger.org.mortbay.log = INFO


# File settings
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=c:\\Combo.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

So when I try to execute the test:

public class LoginTests extends BaseTest {

```
@Test (priority = 0, description="Invalid Login Scenario with wrong username and password.")
public void invalidLoginTest_InvalidUserNameInvalidPassword () {
    Log.info("Debug message");
}
```

I'm getting the stacktrace which start with:

[image]

and finished with:

[image]

The console contains a lot of lines (several hundred) with text `2020-11-05 23:00:51 PlaceholderResolver [main] [WARN] Value not resolved by key: project_report_directory`

And veri long stactrace with `java.lang.StackOverflowError`:

[image]

What means this error, and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs when file `lo4j.properties` is absent.

Example of the file with which the project works well:

```java
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${user.dir}/Log4j/log4j-test-automation.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#do not append the old file. Create a new log file everytime
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-4p] %d{dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss} %t | %m%n
```